# How to pass parameters in return url of vf page:

Tags: visualforce

I am sending parameters in rturn url like below:

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="window.open('/{!list.Id}/e?retURL=apex/Mypage?id={!Event.Id}&{!parameter}')"  value="Edit"  id="edit"/>
```

after doing some action on standard page I want to return back to my vf page with some parameters
but it is returning just one parameters not others like:

```
/apex/Mypage?id={!Event.Id}
```

but I need this url:

```
/apex/Mypage?id={!Event.Id}&{!parameter}'
```

Here parameter is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add query string parameters to retUrl, which is already a query string parameter, you need to URL encode the whole string with the retUrl parameters (including ?, &). This may result in parts of the string being doubly URL encoded. This is to ensure that those parameters are not picked up by the standard page but are passed on through to your VF page (now decoded) and then picked up.

Something like this would work in an outputLink:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!list.Id}/e?retURL=apex/Mypage{!URLENCODE('?id=' + Event.Id + '&parameter=' + parameter)}">
    Edit
</apex:outputLink>
```

This also seems to work with commandLink and onclick:

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="window.open('/{!list.Id}/e?retURL=apex/Mypage{!URLENCODE('?id=' + Event.Id + '&parameter=' + parameter)}')" id="edit">Edit</apex:commandLink>
```

You could also construct the link string on the backend using Apex `EncodingUtil.urlEncode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a parameter, you are only using a value:

Try

```
/apex/Mypage?id={!Event.Id}&myparam={!parameter}';
```

Also make sure the {!parameter} is not null

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing value after &.

This is a good link describing all details of passing params in VF - http://www.forcetree.com/2009/06/passing-parameters-to-visualforce-page.html

for your code, try this -

```
/apex/Mypage?id={!Event.Id}&param={!parameter}';
```